# Not grouping by all columns included in the select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below script where I wish to do a grouping only by CUSTOMER and TYPE, however its forcing me to also group it by p.ID as I am using it in the select statement.
*How can I apply this multiplication logic (*5) and still sum it up for all p.ID and group only by CUSTOMER and TYPE.*

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

```
SELECT       
         CUSTOMER
        ,TYPE
        --,p.ID
        ,CASE
            WHEN p.ID = 'GAX' THEN SUM(QTY) * 5
            ELSE SUM(QTY)
        END AS TOTAL_QTY
INTO TEMP_TABLE
FROM ORDERS o
INNER JOIN PRODUCT p ON o.MATERIAL_ID = p.MATERIAL_ID
GROUP BY CUSTOMER
        ,TYPE
        --,p.ID;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation.  The `case` is the argument to the `sum()`:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, TYPE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.ID = 'GAX' THEN QTY * 5
                ELSE QTY
           END) AS TOTAL_QTY
INTO TEMP_TABLE
FROM ORDERS o INNER JOIN
     PRODUCT p
     ON o.MATERIAL_ID = p.MATERIAL_ID
GROUP BY CUSTOMER, TYPE;
```